# Search for domain names

Tags: search, domain

I want a list of sites that include certain word in its domain name, but not in the path. Example: search for `bicycle` must returns sites like `bicycles.stackexchange.com`, but not `facebook.com/bicycle`.

What site/tool can do this?

Comment: Is the order of this list important? Or do you simply want to query a list of registered domain names? Is the TLD important?

Comment: For the sake of this not seeming like a site request (which is off-topic), could you reformulate this into how to do it with Google (or Bing, etc.) and then branch out from there if you don't get a satisfactory answer?

Comment: FWIW I don't think you can do this with Google or Bing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you can do a search like this using http://www.namedroppers.com/

(Note, I do not have any experience or association with NameDroppers.com, but it looks legitimate to me.)